# DRF TypeError 'type' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I'm making my first DRF api and I get a strange TypeError when I try to access to my data using a GET request, I get this error:

> 'type' object is not iterable

Here are some code snippets bellow.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Expediteur(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    prenom = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tel = models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from polls.serializers import ExpediteurSerializer, DestinataireSerializer, LettrePrioSerializer, TypeLettreRecoSerializer, LettreRecoSerializer, TimbrePrioSerializer, TimbreRecoSerializer
from polls.models import Expediteur, Destinataire, LettrePrio, TypeLettreReco, LettreReco, TimbrePrio, TimbreReco
from rest_framework import status, HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING

import json
import datetime

from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse, Http404
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import user_passes_test
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.utils.timezone import get_current_timezone
from django.db.models.query import QuerySet

# Create your views here.

class ExpeViewSet(APIView):
    QuerySet = Expediteur.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExpediteurSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = ExpediteurSerializer(QuerySet, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.DATA)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from polls.models import Expediteur, Destinataire, LettrePrio, TypeLettreReco, LettreReco, TimbrePrio, TimbreReco


class ExpediteurSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Expediteur
```

I also leave the Traceback for more informations:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://0.0.0.0:8000/polls/expediteur/

Django Version: 1.7.1
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'polls')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  452.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  449.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/mehdi/rendu/ProjectWeek/CUP/polls/views.py" in get
  29.         return Response(serializer.data)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  618.         ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in data
  213.                 self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py" in to_representation
  568.             self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable

Exception Type: TypeError at /polls/expediteur/
Exception Value: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to list all `expediteur` instances, you should use `list` view not `get`. Remember that `get` is for retrieving one instance.

Also, in your imports you have  `from django.db.models.query import QuerySet` and then when you try `ExpediteurSerializer(QuerySet, many=True)` you are trying to serialize `QuerySet` type imported previously. To get your defined `QuerySet`, you need to use `self.` But I recommend use just `queryset`

```
class ExpeViewSet(GenericAPIView):
      queryset = Expediteur.objects.all() 
      serializer_class = ExpediteurSerializer


      def list(self,request):
          queryset  = self.Expediteur.objects.all() 
          serializer = ExpediteurSerializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True)
          return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the code you gave me but I get another error: AtributeError 'ExpeViewSet' object has no attribute 'get_queryset'

Comment: @Mehdi sorry, I fixed, use `QuerySet` or `Expediteur.objects.all()`

Comment: QuerySet is not defined, you mean self.QuerySet but then again QuerySet would only be evaluated once on server start and never get updated.

Comment: @user640916 QuerySet was defined, check OP code.But also I added it in lowercase.

Comment: @levi, check the scope of the variables. QuerySet is not local to the function "list".

Comment: @levi , just tried your solution which seems to work fine, now I have a django error:
HTTP 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
Allow: POST, OPTIONS

{
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}

I guess that is something totally different. Thanks for the help. Both of you ;)

Comment: @Mehdi ah, that is because you need to update your urls.py addining `list` method with a `GET` request.

Answer (score 0):

I saw you use QuerySet, but it should be lowercase.

Try this:

```
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView

class ExpeViewSet(GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Expediteur.objects.all()  # lowercase!
    serializer_class = ExpediteurSerializer

    def get(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(self.get_queryset(), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: in fact that is not the problem.  OP has  `from django.db.models.query import QuerySet` and then he is trying to serialize imported `QuerySet` type. Is not due to lowercase.

Comment: You down vote a working solution? You were assigning something to QuerySet which is a django import and that just is plain wrong. You edited multiple times after my downvote. Be reasonable!

Comment: Edit your answer to upvote, but you also downvoted to a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was not inherited Model from models.Model

e.g. `class Document:
       ...`

which should have been

`class Document(models.Model):
   ...`